# Get all partitioned tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to find all partitioned tables in my DB's , this is the query I've tried

```
SELECT distinct t.name ,  p.partition_number
FROM sys.partitions p
INNER JOIN sys.tables t
on p.object_id = t.object_id
```

but it does not show all the partitioned tables

Comment: What is incorrect about the data that it returns?

Answer (score 0):

This simple query will return more than one row per table, if more than one index is partitioned.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id), * FROM sys.partition_schemes ps
JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.data_space_id = ps.data_space_id
```